# Loading selected column from csv file to dataframe in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to load csv file to a Spark dataframe. The csv file doesn't have any header as such, but I am aware which field corresponds to what. 
The problem is my csv has almost 35 odd fields but I am interested in very limited columns so is there a way by which I can load the selected columns and map them to corresponding fields as defined in my schema.

Let's say we have following CSV:

```
1,Michel,1256,Student,high Street, New Delhi
2,Solace,7689,Artist,M G Road, Karnataka
```

In Scala my Code is something like this .

```
val sample_schema = StructType(Array(StructField("Name", StringType, nullable = false),
      StructField("unique_number", StringType, nullable = false),
      StructField("state", StringType, nullable = false))
val blogsDF = sparkSession.read.schema(sample_schema)
                              .option("header", true)
                              .csv(file_path)
```

This will load the data into a dataframe, but it will not be in the order I want. 
What I want is for csv record to be split and data is loaded as per underlying mapping

```
col1 --> Name
col2 --> unique id
col5 --> state
```

Not sure if we can do this kind of operation before loading data into DataFrame. I know another approach wherein we can load the data into one dataframe, and then select few columns and create another dataframe, just want to check if we can map during data load itself. 
Any help or pointer in this regard will be really helpful.

Thanks 
Ashit

Comment: spark.read.csv().select("_c0","_c1","_c3").withColumnRenamed("_c0","Name")... etc

Comment: I don't think we can do that, because select works on the fields in the dataframe, not on the fields in file. So this will not work I guess.

Comment: What the previous commenter means is to load the CSV without specifying the schema and Spark will automatically name the columns `_c0`, `_c1`, etc. Then you can select the ones you need and rename them accordingly.

Comment: ok.. I got your point, but in that case I can't pass the schema during read operation. As my understanding is the moment I pass the schema the above thing can't be done.Correct me if my understanding is wrong though

Comment: yes when passing schema above thing in my comment cannot be done.. still with the approach you can use cast along with columnRenamed to cast it to appropriate type..

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried it:

```
schema = StructType([StructField("a", IntegerType(), True),
                    StructField("b", IntegerType(), True),
                    StructField("c", StringType(), True),
                    StructField("d", StringType(), True),
                    StructField("e", DoubleType(), True),
                    StructField("f", LongType(), True),
                   ])

df  = spark.read.csv('blablabla', schema=schema)
```